# How can I get fragment value from server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My url is:

```
http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback#state=test&access_token=....
```

But when calling `Request.Url.ToString();` it just outputs

```
http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback
```

How can I get the full url send to the server?

Comment: `myUrl.Substring(myUrl.IndexOf('#') + 1)`

Comment: I's say this is a pretty basic question and you'd probably get a greater benefit from researching this yourself than asking here.

Comment: Sorry, I also need to get the url:"http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback#state=test&access_token=...."

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: No, the hash isn't send to the server. Hence, there is no use in your substring.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't.

There is a big difference between hash (`#`) and query string (`?`). The query string is send to the server, the hash isn't.

So the url send to the server *is*: `http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback`.

The only option you have to get the 'hash' to the server is by using a query string:

```
http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback?state=test&access_token=...
```

Comment: Correct! Fiddler doesn't even allow to use the # symbol in GET requests.

Comment: You are right about that. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Thanks, This is google OAuth callback, so I can't edit it.

Comment: Then there is no way to get it, without some javascript crap.

Answer (score 8):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback#state=test&access_token=....");

// Contains the query
uri.Fragment
```

Results in:

```
#state=test&access_token=....
```

Edit:

To get the current url of website use:

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

In the Request.Url is all the information of the current page and in Request.UrlReffer everything from the previous page.

Note: Request.UrlReferrer is null when there is no previous request (from your website)

Comment: Thanks, I need to get the current url : "http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback#state=test&access_token=...."

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: Request.Url.ToString(); just can get "http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback"

Comment: You are looking for: Uri.AbsoluteUrl

Comment: I'm afraid the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri will only get the URL (http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback), not the hashed values. The fragment will be blank if you took your URL from the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri. Please refer to Patrick's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url=@"http://localhost:4567/Test/Callback#state=test";
var uri = new Uri(url);
var result = uri.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already posted answers to your specific problem.

But it seems like you are developing an ASP.NET website so you should consider using the standard `?` instead of `#` to prefix your query string.

This will allow you to use built-in methods and properties for processing the query string and avoid custom error-prone string processing:

```
string queryString = Request.Url.Query; // gives you "state=test&access_token=...."
```

or access it as a NameValueCollection:

```
string state = Request.QueryString["state"]; // gives you "test"
```

Comment: For some reason, OAuth providers seem to return a fragment (#) containing the access token, instead of using a query string (?). I've seen the issue in ForgeRock, and it looks like the Google OAuth works the same way. I have no idea why they settled on this as a standard.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy the reason is increased security. `#` fragments solely exist client-side and are not transferred over the network, and because the specific OAuth flow you are using is meant for client-side apps (implicit flow I'm guessing), there is no need for the server to access it anyway, so it makes sense. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733863/oauth2-0-implicit-grant-flow-why-use-url-hash-fragments) for a bit more info. There's also the authorization code flow (now recommended everywhere) you could use where the server gets the access token instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript to get the full link then pass it to the code behind

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function JavaScriptFunction() {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnResultValue.ClientID %>').value = document.URL;
    }

</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="0" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button_Get" runat="server" Text="run" OnClick="Button_Get_Click" OnClientClick="JavaScriptFunction();" />
```

then from the code behind get the value of hiddenfield which contains the current full URL

```
protected void Button_Get_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string fullURL = hdnResultValue.Value;
   string URl = fullURL .Substring(fullURL .IndexOf('#') + 1);
}
```

good luck

Comment: This is a C# tagged question. You do not know if this within a context of a web environment. It could be a console app calling an api or something.

Comment: i think that the comments below other answers says that it's a web-based question

Comment: Sorry, but i only see comments about asking for the url too. Never mentioned a web environment.

Comment: a bit late, but there is an 'asp.net' tag, so it looks to be about a web environment